# How to create a parameterized jar where the parameters are passed by users at run time

Tags: java, executable-jar

My learning plan is to create a parameterized jar and execute it from cmd line. Example scenario: I am creating a simple program to copy a dir from a source path and pasting it in a target path. For this the below code is used.

```
Public static void main(String args[]){
 String sourcepth="samplepath";
 String targetpath="samplepath";
 FileUtils.copyDirectorytoDirectory(sourcepth,targetpath); 
}
Regret is any errors
```

My expectation is to get the input for sourcepth and targetpath from cmd line. In such case how should i modify the code.

Comment: you can get it as a command line arguments by using the args array

Comment: You should use `args`; you can pass anything there "somehow" — but be aware of the security implications of using something like that (but you can discard this advice if you are just learning/playing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> String args[] array that you pass to your main method is the arguments that will be taken from the bash command you use to execute your program. Given this simple program:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(args != null && args.length > 0
            ? args[0]
            : "No parameter given");
}
```

If you execute it like this:

```
java NameOfClass "my argument"
```

The output will be `my`, however, if you just run it with no arguments:

```
java NameOfClass
```

You will get `No parameter given`

More info here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Its works great for me. I am using this for internal purposes for a project.